# Filling an array with inputted variables in MIPS assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips

I am trying to create an integer array in MIPS wherein the user can choose the size and numbers that will be stored. For some reason, my program does not branch to the end loop when the array is full.

I apologize if the solution is glaringly obvious. This is homework, so I am not looking to plagiarize full code answers, but rather if I could be pointed towards the right direction I would appreciate it greatly. Thanks for looking.

```
    .text
        .globl __start     # for PCSPIM //main for qtspim instead of __start
__start:
        la $a0,pr1          # Ask user for amount of integers desired to be entered
        li $v0,4            # a0 = address of string
        syscall            # v0 = 4, indicates display a string

        li $v0,5            # Command to read an integer
        syscall

        sw $v0,count        # Store int read into count

        lw $t0,array        # Point t0 to array
        lw $t1,count        # Point t1 to count

M_LOOP:
        la $a0,pr2          # Prompt for integer
        li $v0,4            # a0 = address of string
        syscall            # v0 = 4 

        li $v0,5            # Command to read an integer
        syscall

        beqz $v0, E_LOOP
        sw $v0, array($t0)  # Move the integer into the array
        addi $t0,$t0,4      # Increment count by 4
        sub $t1,$t1,1           # Subtract 1 from $t1

        bnez $t0,M_LOOP

E_LOOP:
        li $v0,10              # End Of Program 
        syscall               # Call to system

        .data
array:  .space      100
pr1:    .asciiz     "Amount of integers to be entered: "
pr2:    .asciiz     "Integer to be inserted into array: "
newl:   .asciiz     "\n"
count:  .word       0
```

Comment: I guess `bnez $t0,M_LOOP` should use `$t1` instead of `$t0`.

Comment: *Thank you* for not asking for code outright. Meanwhile, we need to know the exact error or errant output you're getting. If it's in here, it isn't easy to spot. See [How to Ask](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Should probably be `bnez $t1, M_LOOP`

Comment: Thanks everyone. Ashamed I didn't see that. Problem solved!